# Unable to check checkboxes for wxTreeListCtrl items using mouse click

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxTreeListCtrl with wxTL_CHECKBOX style, but for some reason I am not able to check checkbox using mouse click, though I can do it by pressing SPACE. Is this normal, or am I missing something ?

My code:

```
// .h file
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/treelist.h>

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);

private:
    void OnTreeLeftDown (wxMouseEvent& evt);

private:
    enum 
    {
        TreeListId = 1
    };

    wxTreeListCtrl*  m_treeList;
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

// .cpp file
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE (MyFrame, wxFrame)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame ("Hello World", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(600, 400));
    frame->Show (true);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame (const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxFrame (NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    m_treeList = new wxTreeListCtrl (this, TreeListId, wxPoint (10, 10), wxSize(600, 400), wxTL_CHECKBOX);
    m_treeList->AppendColumn (L"Item Name");

    m_treeList->AppendItem (m_treeList->GetRootItem(), L"Test");
    m_treeList->AppendItem (m_treeList->GetRootItem(), L"Another one");

    CenterOnScreen ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out in wxWidgets forum it is a bug in 3.0.0
Here is bug url http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15731